# Snow Leopard: make command not found, even though XCode is installed?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, xcode, make

So I've installed XCode on Snow Leopard. Why am I getting messages like this:

```
sudo: make: command not found
```

What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

### Solution:

I'm not sure what happened, but I was able to fix the problem by [downloading the newest version of XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html) and reinstalling it. Now I can see that I have make installed correctly.

```
$ which make
/usr/bin/make
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you installed the Apple Developer tools, did you also install the "Unix Development" package?  From the [Xcode 3.2.2 developer tools for Mac SDK 10.6 and iPhone SDK 3.2](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.2_developer_tools_beta_20728/about_xcode_3.2.2.pdf) README file:

> Installation
>
> The Xcode and iPhone SDK installer provides six options for configuring the installation from the “Customize...” button:
>
> ...
>
> - UNIX Development. Command-line tools used for UNIX-based development. Its components are always placed in /usr - only one version installed at a time.

I believe that is what triggers putting the utilities into /usr/bin ...

Comment: just to help lion users with this issue. After installing XCode (4.3.3 at time of writing), inside Xcode -> Developer Tools -> More Developer Tools... it takes you to apple developer website where after a few hoops you are able to search for "make" or "gcc" and you can download "Command Line Tools for XCode"

Answer (score 11):

Go to Preferences in Xcode, choose *Downloads* and install *Command Line Tools*.

[image]

Comment: I accidentally put in the wrong credentials, and now it won't let me change my original credentials. It just says I'm not registered every time I try and click install.

Comment: This XCode screen is taken on Lion, the question was about Snow Leopard on which XCode version is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having a similar problem in which the make command had mysteriously disappeared from my Mac after upgrading. I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion. I also upgraded from Xcode 4.2 to 4.3.

However, after the installations seemingly went fine make was nowhere to be found. It seems that installing the new Xcode just wiped it out.

I ended up using the GCC installer from the brilliant Kenneth Reitz, which worked perfectly:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Comment: Chances are, [you didn't install the command line tools](http://superuser.com/a/390968/22317) for Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PATH contains the directory that includes make.

Comment: which directory would that be?

Comment: @misbehavens /usr/bin/