# Make on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: mac, xcode, make

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Snow Leopard: make command not found, even though XCode is installed?](https://superuser.com/questions/155188/snow-leopard-make-command-not-found-even-though-xcode-is-installed)

How do I install GNU make on my Mac? I tried installing it from MacPorts, but that didn't work. I have XCode (version 3.2.6) installed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to install [Xcode 4.1](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12) to get a suitable version of `make`.

<sub>Related on Stack Overflow: [Where can I find “make” program for Mac OS X Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767481/where-can-i-find-make-program-for-mac-os-x-lion)</sub>