# Homebrew doesn't find XCode 4.3

Tags: macos, osx-lion, xcode, homebrew

When I try to install something with homebrew I get an error message that it does not find XCode. But I just installed XCode 4.3 and also did a reboot.

```
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ernst$ brew install macvim
Warning: Xcode is not installed! Builds may fail!
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/bin/cc
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ernst$
```

Any ideas?

Update:

```
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ernst$ which cc
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ernst$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
admins-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ernst$
```

Comment: Are the requires files in `/Developer/usr/bin`? Does it help to change the `$PATH`?

Comment: Does it work when you specify `--use-llvm`?

Comment: --use-llvm did not help, same error message.

Comment: There's no /Developer directory.

Comment: What could I change in $PATH?

Comment: Did you actually *install* Xcode or just *download it* from the App Store? There should be an application named "Install Xcode" in your applications folder.

Comment: It's installed, I can start it and create new projects.

Comment: Where was the Xcode application bundle installed to? What is the output of `which cc` on the command line? What's the output of `echo $PATH`? Did you download it from the Apple Developer Connection website or the App Store?

Comment: The download is from the App Store.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution [in Homebrew's issues page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10244#issuecomment-4013781). Open Xcode, open Preferences, select Downloads, and install Command Line Tools. Once it is installed Homebrew should work.

Comment: Weird cause I was under the impression that you wouldn't need XCode to get those tools but couldn't find them anywhere. Thanks for this answer, been frustrating me.

Comment: You can download the command-line tools separately from http://developer.apple.com/downloads (you need an Apple ID). The package requires Lion. For more details: http://kennethreitz.com/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew.html

Comment: I installed brew and *only* the command line tools, but brew doctor says I need to run xcode-select to set the path - what do I set it to?

Comment: According to my system, `xcode-select -print-path` == `/`. So I guess set it to the root path. I recall this was part of the problem, it gets set or used to be set to `/Developer` when the developer tools were installed to `/Developer/usr/bin`, which changed in the newer version. YMMV.