# MonoMac project fails, ibtool returned error code 1, No Xcode folder is set

Tags: xcode, monodevelop

I have a new MacBook and have installed Xcode 4.3 with the command line tools. [Homebrew is working](https://superuser.com/a/390968/50958) so everything seems ok so far. I then installed  MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5.

If I create a new MonoMac project then build, it fails with the following error:

> Error: ibtool returned error code 1 (MonoMacTest)

If I run `ibtool` (no arguments) in Terminal I get the following:

```
Bens-MacBook-Air:~ ben_scott$ ibtool
xcode-select: Error: No Xcode folder is set. Run xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path> to > set the path to the Xcode folder.
Error: /usr/bin/xcode-select returned unexpected error.
Bens-MacBook-Air:~ ben_scott$
```

How do I fix this and get MonoDevelop working with MonoMac projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that setting the Xcode folder path to `/` works, or at least now I'm getting a different error (something about the MainMenu NIB file...). Set the path with this:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me (on Lion):

```
sudo ./xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

It depends where the Xcode is installed. It used to be installed in `/Developer`
but now when installed from the App Store it is installed in the `/Applications` folder like all the rest.

And yes, it is an integration bug, where each application assumes the other is responsible for it and eventually no one does.

Comment: worked! but without './' -> sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app Thanks!!!